# RPI 2 is not accessible after a week

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I have a RPI2 that acts as a web server and contains a web application for heating control. Everything was working fine about 6 months. Now, the RPI2 can't be accessed through ssh client or ftp server. Also, when I enter the URL of the web application it cant be accessed , I can only access the www folder of the web server ( The IT WORKS page ). When i plug off the RPI2 from power, and plug it in again, everything works for about a week ( i can access the web app, ssh is accessible, ftp is accessible). After a week passes the RPI2 gets stuck again. It seem that after a week of runtime i am losing permissions? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to check the logs for those services to see if they give any clue as to why they are crashing or shutting down.
If there was no clue there, then you would need to look at the OS level.